# How can I get all the values from multiple select inputs on a button click? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, ref

I'm creating a questionnaire where the values of the select inputs are collected and averaged to produce a score. Seems easy enough, but I'm struggling to get them. Currently my goal is just to get the values to begin with, but it seems like I can only get the value for the last select input when I click the submit button, calling the `handleClick()` event.

I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Through some guides I've seen others use the `useRef()` function, but I've seen the `createRef()` as well.

I'm using Gatsby JS and GraphQL for the data query. I appreciate any advice.

```
const Questionnaire = (props: Props) => {
  const data = props.data!
  const questionnaire = data.allContentfulQuestionnaire.edges
  let i = 0

  const selectInput = useRef()

  const handleClick = () => {
    for (const r in selectInput) {
      console.log("foo: ", selectInput.current.value)
      console.log("bar: ", r.valueOf())
    }
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Container>
        {questionnaire?.map(({ node }: any) => (
          <>
            <h2>{node?.title}</h2>
            {node?.questions?.map(({ answers, question }: any) => (
              <Question key={question?.id}>
                <P>
                  {++i}. {question?.question}
                </P>

                <select key={question?.id} ref={selectInput}>
                  <option>Select Response</option>
                  {answers.map(({ title, id, score }: any) => (
                    <option key={id} value={score}>
                      {title}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              </Question>
            ))}
          </>
        ))}

        <Submit onClick={handleClick}>Submit</Submit>
      </Container>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `on change` on select as `callback` ??

Comment: `useRef` for only one context.

Comment: sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/handling-multiple-select-rows-in-react-select-0n6ib

Comment: REACT ABUSING - AVOID keeping state in DOM ... `useState` ... read react docs/tutorials (handling events) !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with ref, you need `n` ref for `n` fields/select

```js
const Questionnaire = (props: Props) => {
  const data = props.data!
  const questionnaire = data.allContentfulQuestionnaire.edges
  let i = 0

  const refs = node?.questions?.map(q => q.node?.questions?.map(useRef));

  const handleClick = () => {
    // You have nested array of refs so you can get the desired values
    console.log(refs[0][0].current.value);
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Container>
        {questionnaire?.map(({ node }: any, outerIndex) => (
          <>
            <h2>{node?.title}</h2>
            {node?.questions?.map(({ answers, question }: any, innderIndex) => (
              <Question key={question?.id}>
                <P>
                  {++i}. {question?.question}
                </P>

                <select key={question?.id} ref={refs[outerIndex][innderIndex]}>
                  <option>Select Response</option>
                  {answers.map(({ title, id, score }: any) => (
                    <option key={id} value={score}>
                      {title}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              </Question>
            ))}
          </>
        ))}

        <Submit onClick={handleClick}>Submit</Submit>
      </Container>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!! I added `questonnaire` to `const refs = questionnaire?.node?.questions?.map((q: any) => {
    q.questionnaire?.node?.questions?.map(useRef)
  })` because it said node wasn't defined.

Currently I'm getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" at `<select key={question?.id} ref={refs[outerIndex][innerIndex]}>`. Any ideas? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Have you console.log(refs), what's its value

Comment: The page breaks and the same error appears:
"TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: Code should not break after `const refs` assignment, print it there